# smtplib.SMTP.send_message replaces "From" with ">From" in text content

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Consider the following example to send an email via smtplib and email libraries in Python 3:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Make the email:
msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content("""
Hi,
From foo
from bar
 From baz
""")

msg['Subject'] = 'Example'
msg['From'] = "me@example.com"
msg['To'] = "you@example.com"

# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

This will produce an email that looks like this:

```
Message-ID: <...>
Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2022 12:01:47 -0700 (PDT)
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Example
From: me@example.com
To: you@examole.com


Hi,
>From foo
from bar
 From baz
```

Note how `From` was turned to `>From` in the body of the email if it is in the beginning of a line. I would like to not put the `>` in there if there is *From* used in the email text. I suspect this is to prevent the `from` being injected in the body if it was not defined in the headers but in my case it is defined.

Interestingly, this is not in the `EmailMessage` itself:

```
>>> print(msg)
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Example
From: me@example.com
To: you@example.com


Hi,
From foo
from bar
 From baz
```

It seems the `\nFrom` in the body is turned to `\n>From` in the method `SMTP(...).send_message` and it is not caused by the email policy in the message itself.

So the question is how to stop replacing the `\nFrom` with `\n>From` in the text body when sending emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer and decided to document it if someone else stumbles on the same issue. In short, the answer is that there is not much you can do.

Basically this is what happens in [smtplib.SMTP.send_message](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/smtplib.py#L983):

```
def send_message(self, msg, from_addr=None, to_addrs=None,
                 mail_options=(), rcpt_options=()):
        ...
    else:
        g = email.generator.BytesGenerator(bytesmsg)
    g.flatten(msg_copy, linesep='\r\n')
```

Note how the generator is created by just passing the `bytesmsg` as an argument.

Then the [initiation of the generator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/email/generator.py#L62):

```
def __init__(self, outfp, mangle_from_=None, maxheaderlen=None, *,
             policy=None):
    ...
    if mangle_from_ is None:
        mangle_from_ = True if policy is None else policy.mangle_from_
    self._fp = outfp
    self._mangle_from_ = mangle_from_
    self.maxheaderlen = maxheaderlen
    self.policy = policy
```

Only the `outfp` is passed (the `bytesmsg`). The policy is None thus the `mangle_from_` is always `True` in the smtplib's `send_message` method.

After a couple of method calls, a method is called that executes [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/email/generator.py#L252):

```
...
if self._mangle_from_:
    payload = fcre.sub('>From ', payload)
self._write_lines(payload)
...
```

This adds the `>` in front of `n\From` in the text content of an email.

Therefore, it seems one cannot get rid of replacing `From` to `>From` in the text body. You may subclass the method, copy the code and fix the policy yourself but that won't be clean.